# excluding foreign key fields from django forms

Tags: django

Assume following models.

```
class Address(models.Model):
    house_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street_1 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    street_2 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    postal_area = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class RegisteredUser(User):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)        
    registered_date = models.DateTimeField('registered_date')
```

My question is how do I exclude address field from a Django form. Currently it gives a list box to select an address.

My Form code is:

```
class CreateRegUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_email = forms.EmailField(
        label="Confirm email",
        required=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = RegisteredUser
        exclude = ('password','last_login','is_superuser','is_staff','is_active','date_joined','registered_date','address_id',)
```

Comment: Show the code of your form, please

Answer (score 1):

Just add address in exclude list

```
class CreateRegUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_email = forms.EmailField(
        label="Confirm email",
        required=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = RegisteredUser
        exclude = ('address','password','last_login','is_superuser','is_staff','is_active','date_joined','registered_date','address_id',)
```

Comment: oh, I've used addredd_id instead. Thank you for pointing out that.